# Is there a device to detect roof leaks?

Tags: sensors

I just had my roof redone and solar panels installed on the roof. As we're getting into the rainy season I've been concerned about the potential for leaks in my roof with all the new hardware. Is there a device-type that I can look up that's specifically intended for detecting roof leaks?

If there isn't an out-of-the-box solution (yet), would it be appropriate to use an array of water detection sensors, humidity sensors, or otherwise?

My initial thought was to rig some sort of plastic tarp lining the inside of the roof to funnel any leaks to a central spot with a simple water detection sensor. But, that sounds a bit hacky and may introduce more problems.

Comment: Interesting question! It may be possible you could get hints on applicable methods on [home improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: an array of humidity sensors might work ... several remotely controlled webcams could be used to survey the attic in an event of localized high humidity detection

Comment: I would think that any type of water sensor downhill of roof penetrations would be appropriate. i.e. where the bolts for the panel mounting brackets penetrate the roof is going to be one of the first places water will work its way through, so put a water detector just downhill from there. Also, any place that pipes or wiring penetrate the roof.

Comment: I doubt that using a plastic tarp to line the inside of the roof would be easy nor lasting. Under roof temperatures can get quite high, depending on locale and season, and plastic tarps will begin to degrade. Another consideration is proper airflow within the attic space that is needed for cooling and moisture control. Personally, I think a visual inspection after rain would be the most effective approach.

Comment: just curious, what if you layed thin strips of aluminum tape, and then joined each even # strip to the 2nd contact and each odd strip to the first contact of a water sensor. That way, if any water falls on the tape, it would at minimum connect 2 of the adjacent (but not touching) thin strips (if the strips are thin enough - like 1cm) - which would connect the water sensor's contacts, causing detection. Im not sure if this will work in practice due to resistance or being scaled up, but it is an idea. Another idea if it is too large would be to tile small units of these, each with own sensor.